# Find a replace middle of string in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have roughly 250 fields under the key 'display_meta' where I need to change a part of the strings.

An example of the string would be:

Beginning of string
universal identifier
Middle of string
universal identifier
End of string

I need to update and replace the middle of string for all the fields, without affecting beginning or end of string; how might I do this?

The beginning and end of strings will be different each time, but there are universal identifiers that let me specify which bit I want to run the find and replace on.

Is this possible using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to run at least version 10.0.5.

Then use [regexp_replace](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/).